# jQuery scroll element with window is stuttering

Tags: jquery

I did make a function to scroll the div `.header-menu` with the window but the first few seconds the menu is stuttering when scrolling done. After scrolling a while it does not stutter anymore.

Here is the script I am using:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        $('.header-menu').stop().css('top', $(this).scrollTop());      
    });
});
```

How can I make this code better so it goes fluidly in stead of stuttering?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: are you trying to mimic position: fixed in javascript?

Comment: i think you are looking foe animate() instead of css i guess

Comment: It stutters because JS performance is relatively poor in most browsers. Use CSS instead; `position: fixed; top: 0;`

Comment: or if you are not looking for menu to be attached on load but on scroll to its position check sticky-kit.js plugin